# Error when generating a site from a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, designer-workflow, site-template

I have been using a site template successfully to create new subsites. But recently, when I used it again (after a pause of around 2 weeks), I got the error message that ExpirationWorkflow Feature and IssueTrackingWorkflow Feature need to be activated. I don't remember having deactivated these features and don't even know where to find them.

For information, the website has got publishing feature activated, but that's not something that was changed recently.

The exact error message is as below.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, firstly, install SharePoint Online Client Components SDK, and then use PowerShell script to enable the SPO Feature based on the Feature ID.

Check the post to get the relevant script: [MobileExcelWebAccess Feature -Site Template Error](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/MobileExcelWebAccess-Feature-Site-Template-Error/td-p/2531)